# Reliable method to replicate data warehouse from OCI to BigQuery daily without using Data Fusion

Tags: google-bigquery, replication, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to replicate a complete data warehouse from OCI Oracle Cloud Infrastructure to GCP BigQuery daily. However, I am facing some challenges as the replication needs to happen from the GCP side and not OCI. Additionally, I am not able to use Data Stream or Data Fusion as they require Execute_Catalog role which is not approved to be granted.

Currently, I am using Python scripts that run on Cloud Run and Cloud Scheduler to achieve the replication. However, I would like to know if there is another reliable method to achieve the replication.

Can anyone suggest a reliable method to replicate a complete data warehouse from OCI Oracle Cloud Infrastructure to GCP BigQuery daily without using Data Stream or Data Fusion? Any suggestions on alternatives or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way to replicate data to bigquery is using datastream and datafusion. Does this [link](https://hevodata.com/blog/oracle-to-bigquery-etl/) help you?

Comment: Both need Execute_Catalog role form OCI which is not valid, plus data fusion is really expensive option.

Comment: Can you follow this gcp documentation to [replicate](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/migration/migration-overview) data?